# How do I list items horizontally in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-lists

I tried various solutions found on Stack Overflow and elsewhere but nothing works. I list my items with a foreach loop, they appear vertically but I want them to be listed horizontally.

This is the code in my View:

```
<ul>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h3>       <br />
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VariesUntil): @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VariesUntil)  <br />
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ZipId): @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ZipId)    <br />
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: A little bit of css will fix this, its not really an issue with your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ul li {display:inline-block;}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=nPbukAhAIt)

@HukurHaf's answer is correct unless there aren't H3 or input tags inside `li`.

so

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

with `display:inline;` will render side by side but the moment you put H3 or input tag then it will not render side by side.

Comment: is it possible to only display 4 items per line?

Answer (score 3):

ul li { display:inline; }

In your CSS will do the trick.

Comment: You are doing something wrong.  This is as trivial as it gets when it comes to CSS.  Show us some code.

Comment: Agreed @HaukurHaf.  Something's surely not right.  I'd recommend using FireBug or similar tool to see what could be wrong with the generated HTML.